# Running Tensorflow example for RNNs

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to run a code as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/recurrent/index.html).
I have a anaconda enviroment with tensorflow installed via pip installation.

When trying to run the example on the link provided I have a issue. The first one was that the **file:ptb_word_lm.py** wasn't present on my installation. I just copied the file from github and tried to run anyway. I got the following error when running `python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=/tmp/simple-examples/data/ --model small`

error message:

```
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:105] Couldn't open CUDA library libcudnn.so. LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/danielmoreira/anaconda2:/home/danielmoreira/anaconda2/lib:/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:
I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:3448] Unable to load cuDNN DSO
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 361, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/danielmoreira/anaconda2/envs/tensorenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 321, in main
    train_input = PTBInput(config=config, data=train_data, name="TrainInput")
  File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 85, in __init__
    self.input_data, self.targets = reader.ptb_producer(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ptb_producer'
```

I have found people on google suggesting to change the line `from tensorflow.models.rnn.ptb import reader` to just `import reader`, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Does anyone know the possible solution?
I'm using **Python 2.7.12** and Tensorflow version seems to be **0.11.0rc2**

Comment: You probably have a broken installation. Try `import inspect` and `print inspect.getfile(reader)` just before the call.

Comment: it returns: `/home/danielmoreira/anaconda2/envs/tensorenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/reader.pyc`

Comment: That seems to be the correct one. Can you look at the file `reader.py` file in the same directory and see if it has a `def ptb_producer`?

Comment: It didn't have! There seems to have another function there with another name (ptb_iterator), I added the ptb_producer from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/reader.py on my reader.py file and it seems to be working now. Thanks for your time.